# Regular expression C#

Tags: c#, regex

Having trouble determining if a file name conforms to a specific convention as follows. Using regular expression in C# .Net 4.0.

Valid Format: `xxxxT_SSS_sss[i]_t#y.png`
  where

`// x = Any single character.

// T = Digit: 1 to 7 inclusive.

// _SSS = Positive Integer: 000 to 999 inclusive. Always padded with leading zeros.

// _sss = Positive Integer: 000 to 999 inclusive. Always padded with leading zeros.

// i = Random text of any length including any characters. Will always be enclosed in square [] brackets. Optional.

// _t = Positive Integer: 0 to 999 inclusive. Not padded. Optional.

// #y = Positive Integer: 0 to 999 inclusive. Not padded. Optional.`

**UPDATE**

Valid file names:

`File1_000_000.png

File1_000_000_1.png

File1_000_000#2.png

File1_000_000_1#2.png

File1_000_000[text].png

File1_000_000[text]_1.png

File1_000_000[text]#2.png

File1_000_000[text]_1#2.png`

The regex I've been trying is:

`^(.{4}\\d_\\d{3}_\\d{3}(\\[\\w\\s]+\\])?(_\\d{1,3})?(\\#\\d{1,3})?)`

This returns true for all the sample file names BUT, if I change `File1_000_000[text]_1#2.png` to `File1_000_000[text]_#2.png` by deleting the digit `1`, it still returns true. The underscore is a part of the `_t`.

Comment: Can you qualify what you mean by "character" for "x".  Digits and word characters? In the meantime, will assume you mean legal filename characters for Windows (since this is a C# question)

Comment: "// T = Digit: 2 to 7 inclusive." - but your example is File1. Do you mean [1-7]?

Comment: "x" could be any letter, digit, whitespace or legal file character.

Comment: "T": Yes typo. It can range between 1 to 7 inclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question on regex that doesn't involve HTML parsing, is a rarity!

Try the following:

```
@"^.{4}[2-7](_\d{3}){2}(\[.*?\])?(_\d{1,3})?(#\d{1,3})?\.png$"
```

This breaks down into:

```
^             Start of string
.{4}          Any character, exactly 4 times
[2-7]         A number in the range 2 - 7 once
(_\d{3}){2}   An underscore followed by 3 numbers, twice
(\[.*?\])?    An opening square bracket followed by any number of characters and closed by a square bracket 0 or 1 times
(_\d{1,3})?   An underscore followed by at least 1 and up to 3 numbers 0 or 1 times
(#\d{1,3})?   A pound (#) followed by at least 1 and up to 3 numbers 0 or 1 times
\.png$        Ending in .png
```

Comment: Regex tips: `[\d]` = `\d`, `{0,1}` = `?`. Also, you need to escape the `.` in `.png`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to extract these matched parts using the same RegEx instance? I've been manually parsing otherwise.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Yes, any portion in braces forms a capture group. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx for some more information on grouping.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just rewrite one, here:

```
^.{4}[2-7](_\d{3}){2}(\[[^\]]*\])?(_\d{1,3})?(\#\d{1,3})?\.png$
```

The problem right now is that you're not matching `.png` and you're not anchoring the end - the match ends prematurely. Also, you can avoid the double-escaping by prefixing your string with `@`:

```
@"^.{4}[2-7](_\d{3}){2}(\[[^\]]*\])?(_\d{1,3})?(\#\d{1,3})?\.png$"
```

Comment: If I add braces to enclose content after start and before end like so: @"^(.{4}[2-7](_\d{3}){2}(\[[^\]]*\])?(_\d{1,3})?(\#\d{1,3})?\.png)$", does that have any implications?

Comment: @RaheelKhan: No. Why would you do it, though?

Answer (score 1):

Based on you "valid format", this will do the trick

```
^(?i)([a-z]{4}[2-7](_\d{3}){2}(\[.*?[^0-9]\])?(_\d{1,3}?)?(#\d{1,3}?)?\.png)$
```

remove **(?i)** to make the match case sensitive, and change **[2-7]** to **[1-7]** to make it match the files you gave (you said valid were 2-7, but your sample files are *File1...*)

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
^.{4}[2-7]{3}(_[0-9]{3}){2}(\[.+?\])?(_[1-9][0-9]{0,2})?(#[1-9][0-9]{0,2})?\.png$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@"^.{4}[2-7](_\d{3}){2}(\[.+\])?(_\d{1,3})?(\#\d{1,3})?\.png$"
```

Answer (score 0):

This unit test will fail because you have specified the pattern must have an integer 2-7 at the 4th character positionm, where as `File1` has `1`.

```
[Test]
public void StackOverflow()
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^.{4}[2-7](_\d{3}){2}(\[[^\]]+\])?(_\d{1,3})?(#\d{1,3})?\.png$");

    Assert.IsTrue(pattern.IsMatch("File1_000_000.png"));
    Assert.IsTrue(pattern.IsMatch("File1_000_000_1.png"));
    Assert.IsTrue(pattern.IsMatch("File1_000_000#2.png"));
    Assert.IsTrue(pattern.IsMatch("File1_000_000_1#2.png"));
    Assert.IsTrue(pattern.IsMatch("File1_000_000[text].png"));
    Assert.IsTrue(pattern.IsMatch("File1_000_000[text]_1.png"));
    Assert.IsTrue(pattern.IsMatch("File1_000_000[text]#2.png"));
    Assert.IsTrue(pattern.IsMatch("File1_000_000[text]_1#2.png"));

    Assert.IsFalse(pattern.IsMatch("File1_000_000[text]_#2.png"));
}
```